# Problem in "Integrate WSDK into Application" Tutorial DJI-SDK

Tags: c#, uwp, dji-sdk, visual-studio-2019

I follow this tutorial https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html

I have this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7069  Reference to type 'Task<>' claims it is defined in 'System.Runtime', but it could not be found DJIWSDKDemo C:\Users\almendro.avellano\source\repos\DJIWSDKDemo\DJIWSDKDemo\MainPage.xaml.cs 61  Active
```

If I comment that lines and run it, show me the next error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
HResult=0x80131604
Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source=
StackTrace:
Inner Exception 1:
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040
```

I am using VS 2019.. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with the code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Same trouble with VS2017 at line:

```
var productType = (await DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetProductHandler(0).GetProductTypeAsync()).value;
```

Additional to error, there are 11 warnings related to conflicts between versions of `System.Threading, System.Runtime`, etc.

May be a problem with VS or Universal Windows reference.